# Why does Firefox replay css animations in reverse?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

As shown in the codepen below, the nav a links fade in as they should, but then when hovered they seem to replay the animation in reverse and then forward again really quickly. It's really odd. http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/wBMVdm

```
<header>
  <h1>BEN MILDREN</h1>
  <p>Designer and Developer</p>
</header>
<nav>
  <a>About</a>
  <a>Portfolio</a>
  <a>Blog</a>
  <a>Contact</a>
</nav>




<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,700,800|Gentium+Book+Basic:400,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/reserve/D9xlw7UxTBqQw5sLf8cJ_reef%20insp-72.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&s=a46f72e373f7af2b3bba993f565e24be);
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

$color: #4C5C58;
$color-light: #5B6B67;

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  left: calc(50% - 182px);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: anim2 1s ease-in-out 2.5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim1 {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim2 {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px);
  }
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim2 {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px);
  }
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: $color;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: anim1 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: anim1 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: $color-light;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: anim1 1.5s ease-in-out 0.3s forwards;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 183px);
  top: 45%;
}

a {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  background: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: $color-light;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: double 3px $color-light;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 72px;
  top: 38px;
}

nav p {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 100px;
}

a:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3s forwards;
 animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3s forwards;
}

a:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3.1s forwards;
  animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3.1s forwards;
}

a:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3.2s forwards;
  animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3.2s forwards;
}

a:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3.3s forwards;
  animation: anim1 1s ease-in-out 3.3s forwards;
}
```

Comment: You have different behaviours, on Chrome works fine, on IE is a disaster, but your specific issue is related to FF

Comment: Yeah, I know it's related to FF, that's the question...

Comment: At least on your header and p selectors you have only specified the -webkit- prefixed animation and not the universal animation.  I'm not sure if that's the only issue, but it's at least one issue.